# False eof from feof() with sockets fgets

Tags: php, fgets, fsockopen, feof

I have inherited a piece of code which uses the `fetchURL()` function below to grab data from a url. I've just noticed that it is often getting `feof()` returning true before the full page of data is retrieved. I have tried some tests and using `CURL` of `file_get_contents()` both retrieve the full page every time.

The error is intermittent. *On 9 calls, sometimes 7 will complete successfully and sometimes only 4. A particular 4 of the 9 (they are get requests with just a changing query string) always complete successfully.* I have tried reversing the order of the requests and the same 4 query strings are still always successful whilst the remainder sometimes work and sometimes don't.
So it "seems" that the data being returned may have something to do with the problem, but it's the intermittent nature that has got me foxed. The data returned in each case is always the same (as in, every time I make a call with a query string of `?SearchString=8502806` the page returned contains the same data), but sometimes the full page is delivered by `fgets/feof` and sometimes not.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what may be causing this situation? Most other posts O have seen on this subject are regarding the opposite problem whereby `feof()` is not returning true.

```
function fetchURL( $url, $ret = 'body' ) {
    $url_parsed = parse_url($url);
    $host = $url_parsed["host"];
    $port = (isset($url_parsed["port"]))?$url_parsed["port"]:'';
    if ($port==0)
        $port = 80;
    $path = $url_parsed["path"];
    if ($url_parsed["query"] != "")
        $path .= "?".$url_parsed["query"];

    $out = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $host\r\n\r\n";

    $fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    fwrite($fp, $out);
    $body = false;
    $h = '';
    $b = '';
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $s = fgets($fp, 1024);
        if ( $body )
            $b .= $s;
        else
            $h .= $s;
        if ( $s == "\r\n" )
            $body = true;
    }

    fclose($fp);

    return ($ret == 'body')?$b:(($ret == 'head')?$h:array($h, $b));
}
```

Comment: `feof` on sockets is usually (always?) a bad idea, as it'll wait for the server to actually close the socket before proceeding. At the very least you should be sending the `Connection: close` header as well, but I'd seriously recommend a complete rewrite of this code, because it's just bad (no insult intended).

Comment: I am planning on converting to CURL, but I wanted to know what might cause the problem I was seeing. Hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

I see quite a few things wrong with that code.

- Don't ever use `feof` on sockets. It'll hang until the server closes the socket, which does not necessarily happen immediately after the page was received.
- `feof` might return `true` (socket is closed) while PHP still has some data in its buffer.
- Your code to distinguish header from body seems to rely on PHP doing it's job properly, which is generally a bad idea. `fgets` doesn't necessarily read a line, it can also return just a single byte (`\r`, then the next call you might get the `\n`)
- You're not properly encoding the path value

Why don't you just convert your code to use cURL or file_get_contents?

Comment: I am planning on converting to CURL, but I wanted to know what might cause the problem I was seeing. Hence the question.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like a timeout problem to me. See [stream_set_timeout()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php) in the PHP manual.

Comment: Timeouts are like exceptions, you should use them to catch errors if things go wrong, but not for normal usage.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt timeouts are inevitable when getting data from the Internet . It's a reasonable explanation for unpredictable behaviour, no ?

Comment: Yes, timeouts are inevitable, but judging by the question he's not hitting any timeouts. Definitely not with 20% of all requests.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt I agree that it's a bad bit of code, but as the data which is changing is a query string, it's perfectly reasonable that the remote host takes longer on some queries than others. I will say no more.